# reactjs react router picking up changes in the url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I know you can access params id in a url using this.props.match.params. My question is how do you pick up changes the user may have manipulated in the url? 
Ex: orginal url passed from router in props http://localhost:3000/user/3456653/newPage

The user fills out the page and messes with the url params id
Ex: http://localhost:3000/user/888888/newPage

Is there a way I can check if the params are the same before making my api call to store the data? I am using "react-router-dom": "4.2.2"

Answer (score 1):

You can compare your parameters in the `componentDidUpdate` hook of the component given to your `Route` to find out when it changed.

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rjz4q2z45n))**

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const prevPathParameter = prevProps.match.params.pathParameter;
    const newPathParameter = this.props.match.params.pathParameter;

    if (prevPathParameter !== newPathParameter) {
      console.log("pathParameter changed!");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <h1> {this.props.match.params.pathParameter}</h1>;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <Route path="/:pathParameter" component={MyComponent} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am still getting the same pathParameters for prevPathParameter and const newPathParameter

Comment: @Christopher Do you get the same value for `pathParameter` in the example in my answer? That's very odd.

Comment: yes I believe it has to do with the component receiving the props from the router. Since we never leave the page the prevPathParamter equals the newPathParameter because the router never passes new props to the component

Comment: `pathParameter changed!` is clearly logged in the example in my answer, so the `pathParameter` is changed alright.

Comment: yes it changes but only when navigating from the home path page to the about path page. In my scenario, I would not be navigating to another page. I would make some changes to the form and stay on the same page